# Add column to pandas Dataframe (ascending block of numbers)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data looking like this:

```
Col1

aaa1    
bbb1 
ccc1
1
2    
3
aaa2
bbb2
ccc2
4
5
6
```

I want to add a new column to make it look like this:

```
Col1     Col2

aaa1    1
bbb1    1
ccc1    1
1       1
2       1   
3       1
aaa2    2
bbb2    2
ccc2    2
4       2
5       2
6       2
```

So every time a row with aaa1, aaa2... is reached the number in the row of the new column should increase by one. 
Furthermore I want then to delete all rows of the form aaa, bbb and ccc so the result looks like this:

```
Col1     Col2

1       1
2       1   
3       1
4       2
5       2
6       2
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can check if [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) `aaa` and then [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for `Col2` , then check using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) if value is numeric in `Col1` and remove which is not:

```
df['Col2'] = df['Col1'].str.contains('aaa').cumsum()
out = df[pd.to_numeric(df['Col1'],errors='coerce').notna()]
```

---

```
print(out)

   Col1  Col2
3     1     1
4     2     1
5     3     1
9     4     2
10    5     2
11    6     2
```